# Is logging to stdout safe in python when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, stdout

Is python logging module safe when using multiprocessing and logging to `stdout`? (With a `StreamHandler`).

I know it's unsafe when logging with a `FileHandler`, but I can't find information on the interaction between `multiprocessing`, `logging` and `StreamHandler`.